# Anybody know the name of this tattooed fancy Gothic font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: Image showing tattooed lettering]

I need to find the font for these names so I can tell my tattoo artist. I found one called 'Ancient German Gothic' but that only looked similar. I can't find the right one where the J's have the curve, the H has a little branch like thing on the top, the S's are like the S's. Anyone know the font?

Comment: Tattoos can often be hand lettered *based* upon a font, but it's not the same as seeing a font in print. My guess would be you simply need to find a [blackletter](http://www.myfonts.com/search/blackletter/fonts/) font you feel is close.

Comment: Thanks Scott and Andrew. I found a website tattoolettering.net and that gave me the font. After all it is called 'Medieval German'

Answer (score 1):

Look at these two fonts, which could be taken as a base for the tattoo -

[wilhelm-klingspor-schrift](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/alterlittera/wilhelm-klingspor-schrift/)

[image]

[Deutsche Zierschrift](http://www.dafont.com/deutsche-zierschrif.font?text=Johnny%20Jesse%20Joey)

[image]